# Why can't obtain child model object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show some article. And article consists in two model(Article, ArticleHistory).
Now, I just stuck with a problem which I can't display article history columns.

Here's Controller

```
  def show
    binding.pry
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article = Article.get_article(article_id: params[:id], version: @article.current_version)
  end
```

Here's Models

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_histories
  has_many :article_images
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_histories

  scope :get_article, -> (id, version){ joins(:article_histories).merge(ArticleHistory.select_version(id, version))}
end

class ArticleHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article

  scope :select_version, -> (id, version){ where("article_id = ? and version = ?", id, version) }

end
```

And this is view(.slim).

```
h1 = @article.article_histories.title
h2 = t :content
=@article.content.html_safe
h3 = t :category
```

It's argent. Help me, please.

[Appendix]
Error Message is like this

`NoMethodError undefined method 'article_histories'`

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: Thanks! I appended the error on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article = Article.where(id: params[:id]).includes(:article_histories).where(article_history: {version: @article.current_version})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried as you wrote. Regrettably, the error shows as follows.
`undefined method `article_histories' `
This line is the cause of error.
`h1 = @article.article_histories.title`

Comment: `article_histories` is an array, you'll have to loop thru that, there is no `title` on an array.

Comment: Nope, it seems like not an array. The thing is not able to take values on `article_history` or `article_histories`.  The first line above is working. Why second line doesn't take appropriate value?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

`@article.first.article_histories.first.title`

is right answer. The object returns array, I guess.